# Can anybody list all the religion? Or the most commonly known. Also, what to they practice or follow?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, philosophy-of-culture, faith, philosophical-comparison, information

I want to expend my knowledge toward understanding who I am as a human- being and what I belief in. Sometime I don't fully know where I stand and one way to start that is by simply narrowing down what applies and don't applies to me.

Comment: Off topic. Too broad. A list can't be proven to be comprehensive. Also depends on what to count for a religion. Thus opinion based.

Comment: Wikipedia is usually a good place to start when you're interested in a topic.  As far as listing literally all the religions, I really doubt that there's any list that includes "what David Thornley believes", so they're all going to be incomplete.  Good luck with your search.

Comment: This would be too broad to provide in an answer without just providing a link. However, maybe you could restrict the question to something more specific. What are you reading now that is stimulating this question? Also look at the tags here. Click on those you find interesting. They may lead you to the information you want or to a detailed question you might ask. Regardless, welcome to this SE!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a trivial web search turns up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_religious_populations